# Visual Studio not hitting breakpoints unless Symbols are explicitly loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a Web API 2 project where after "refreshing" Windows 10, I can no longer debug because the breakpoints don't get hit (Using Chrome, also tested with Edge, same thing).

I did some digging and managed to get it 'working' by going into `Tools > Options > Debugging > Tick 'Microsoft Symbol Servers'`.

However.

This only worked once, trying to debug again bought back the original problem of breakpoints not being hit. I then found if I restarted VS2015 (Community Edition 64bit - ran as admin), the "Symbols are loading" popup reappears and once all the symbols are loaded, the breakpoints get hit.

This essentially means that I'm having to restart VS every time I want to debug the API.

I've checked the basics, such as `<compilation debug="true">` in the Web.Config and that I'm actually running in the debug mode instead of release. I've also checked that the `debug info` is set to `full` under `Project > Properties > Build > Debug Configuration > Advanced`.

I then thought this could be a permissions issue on folder the symbols get cached too, (After the Win 10 "refresh" I seem to be having permissions trouble on just about every folder, also, emptying the cache and debugging again forces the symbols to be loaded from Microsoft). So I went into `Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols` and found the file path the symbols where stored in. On the parent directory, I set 'Everyone' to have Full Control (just to be sure). -This didn't solve the issue either.

Comment: IMHO, Visual Studio 2010 was the last version that offered a robust debugging experience. The debugger wasn't perfect, but at least it reliably did what it was supposed to be capable of. In later versions of the IDE, weird, unexplained, and often annoying debugger quirks seem to have become a common experience for many... which is a shame. Sorry that I have no helpful answer for you, I'm just saying that you're not alone.

Comment: Some general suggestion, though: **1.** Debugging 64 bit code appears to work less well than debugging 32 bit code (at least for me). **2.** Especially when the browser is a 32 bit process and your code is 64 bit, I noticed that the VS debugger sometimes won't stop at breakpoints.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?